# Rest DELETE verb with matlab's webread/webwrite

Tags: matlab, rest, crud

Is there a way to send PUT and DELETE requests with `webread()` / `webwrite()`?

Trying to do `opt = weboptions('RequestMethod','delete')` gets me the following error message:

```
Error using weboptions (line 223)
Expected RequestMethod to match one of these strings:

'auto', 'get', 'post'

The input, 'delete', did not match any of the valid strings.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB doesn't have full REST capability easily. You can expand it by using urlread2 http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35693-urlread2 or writing your own Java code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why?

Comment: I do not know. Could be that most people don't use MATLAB for the web. Or that The Mathworks doesn't care about web.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2016b this can be done with matlab.net.http.RequestMessage
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/send-http-message.html

```
request=matlab.net.http.RequestMessage('delete',[],matlab.net.http.MessageBody(''))
response=request.send( 'http://stackoverflow.com')
```